# Why am I getting 422 status code during the post endpoint testing, unit testing?

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

During the running test case of my application, I keep on seeing test failed even when the data is well formatted. The following are my code snippets:

I was able to create a new user through its application interface, but trying its behaviour, it was giving me an unexpected error status code, 422. I don't really know what was going wrong with the snippets. Here I have included all the following code for better look into the stated issue.

*For the endpoint* /users

```
@app.route('/users/, methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    try:
         body = request.get_json((
         new_user = body get('user_name', None)
         if user_name is None:
              about(405)
         new_entry = User(new_user)
         new_entry.insert()
         return jsonify({
              'success': True
         )}
   except:
       abort(422)
```

*Here is my* model_class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__='users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String, nullable=False)
     score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, score=0):
         self.name = name
         self.score = score

     def insert(self):
         db.session.add(self)
         db.session.commit()

     def format(self):
         return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'score': self.score
```

*And here is my* test_case_file:

```
class TriviaTestCase(unit test.TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         self.app = create_app()
         self.client = self.app.test_client
         self.database_path = "PostgreSQL://postgres:postgresspass@localhos:5432/user_test_db"
         setup_db(self.app, self database_path)

     self.new_user = {
         "username":"P.Son",
         "score": 0
     }

     def test_create_user(self):
         res = self.client().post("/users", json=self.new_user)
         data = json.loads(res.data)
         
         
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
  
  self.assertEqual(data['success'], True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output of my test:

```
============================
FAIL: test_create_user (__main__.TriviaTestCase)
----------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\...\test_flaskr.py", line 201, in test_create_user
       self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 422 != 200
```

**Note** Other endpoints pass the test but the above endpoint has been failing test. I don't know what was wrong with the snippets I have written.

Comment: Assert that the data you post to your endpoint is actually valid. 422 means that you passed 2 hoops already (you supplied the right content type and it's somehow parse-able as JSON) but the entity could not be processed. A good way would be to put a breakpoint or print statement in method that handles the incoming call.

Comment: Also, check the brackets and braces in your /users endpoint. I copy pasted the code in VsCode and even without the python plugin it already complains about a mismatch. Do you use an IDE to program (such as pycharm or eclipse)? Any decent IDE will tell you that there is something off with the code.

Comment: I use vs code to program.

Comment: With python plugin? If so, check the errors in the endpoint. Missing quotes and mismatching brackets should be obvious.

Comment: you're setting the username to "P.Son", but when you read the data from the request, you're trying to get user_name. also there's a dot missing between "body get(", and a closing quote at '/users/, which turns the whole route into text rather than code.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64: yes and the curly brackets are misaligned at the Jsonify method as well as the double brackets (( in the method call which should be (). These are all very obvious errors when you use an IDE as it will complain about it, hence my remark to OP.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64: the test is passed by create_user() endpoint just by following your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always be logging such errors when they happen in your endpoints.
Second, you are returning the 422 error yourself in case of "any" exception and there is some in your code. One of which is the fact that you are just passing `user_name` to the constructor of the `User` class but there must be a `score` variable present too.
Another problem is that you should pass key-value arguments to the `User` class constructor, not a dictionary.
is should be something like this:

```
         body = request.get_json()
         user_name = body.get('user_name', '')
         score = body.get('score', '')
         if not all([user_name, score]):
             # return some customized error here
         new_entry = User(user_name=user_name, score=score)
```

Also, you should consider some form of input validation rather than just checking the data yourself. Something like Marshmellow would be fine.